# Server side file upload is unstable

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-upload, upload

I have an application that is depending on its ability to upload files.

However im experianceing some problems with my file upload after i changed some of the settings in my PHP.init file.

First some important information:

- The server is an ubuntu 14.04
- i am using `Apache` 2.4

Now it all started with my clients not being able to upload bigger files onto my server. So what i did was change the settings in my `php.ini`:

(note that i am here `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 250M


; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 500M
```

After applying these changes i called the command: `sudo service apache2 restart`

I then attempted to upload a file with the following size: `82.4 MB`

in php i am using the following function to handle my upload:

```
    public function uploadFile()
{
    if ($this->isAjax()) {
        $comp_id = $_POST['comp_id'];
        $name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
        $name = substr($name, strpos($name, "."), strlen($name));
        switch ($name) {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.png':
            case '.jpeg':
            case '.bmp':
            case '.JPG':
            case '.PNG':
            case '.JPEG':
            case '.BMP':
                    $_FILES['file1']["name"] = "image_file".$name;
                break;
            case '.MP4':
            case '.mp4':
                $_FILES['file1']["name"] = "mp4_file".$name;
                break;
            case '.FLV':
            case '.flv':
            $_FILES['file1']["name"] = "flv_file".$name;
                break;
            case '.MP3':
            case '.mp3':
            $_FILES['file1']["name"] = "sound_file".$name;
            break;
            case '.docx':
            case '.txt':
            case '.pdf':
            case '.odt':
            case '.DOCX':
            case '.TXT':
            case '.PDF':
            case '.ODT':
                $_FILES['file1']["name"] = "document_file".$name;
                break;
            default:
                die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
        }
        $location = "./site/resources/upload/test_module/" . $comp_id . "/" . $_FILES['file1']["name"];
        if (!file_exists("./site/resources/upload/test_module/" . $comp_id . "/")) {
            mkdir("./site/resources/upload/test_module/" . $comp_id . "/", 0777, true);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],
            $location);

        chmod($location, 777);
        $path = "/site/resources/upload/test_module/" . $comp_id . "/" . $_FILES['file1']["name"];
        chmod($path, 777);

        switch ($name) {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.png':
            case '.jpeg':
            case '.bmp':
            case '.JPG':
            case '.PNG':
            case '.JPEG':
            case '.BMP':
                $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET image_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                break;
            case '.MP4':
            case '.mp4':
                if ($_FILES['file1']['type'] != 'audio/mp3') {
                    $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET video_mp4_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                } else {
                    $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET sound_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                }
                break;
            case '.FLV':
            case '.flv':
                $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET video_flv_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                break;
            case '.MP3':
            case '.mp3':
                $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET sound_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                break;
            case '.docx':
            case '.txt':
            case '.pdf':
            case '.odt':
            case '.DOCX':
            case '.TXT':
            case '.PDF':
            case '.ODT':
                $this->getDatabase()->prepTemplate('UPDATE test_component SET text_path = ? WHERE id = ?', 'si', array($path, $comp_id));
                break;
            default:
                die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from this function i attempt to set permissions to the folder and file to make sure that i can access them afterwards.

While uploading i tried to follow the process and noticed that no folder is created on the server and no file is added.

So something tells me that the upload failed in some way.

Untill i changed the settings in php.ini i could upload smaller files however right now im not even able to upload files with the size of `4 MB`. (or any other files)

The upload works on my local machine without any issues but not on my server.

Has anyone experianced this before or have any idea of what it might be?

**Update**

After adding an error print i get the following error:

```
    Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/test_learningbank/site/pages/models/TestMaker.php on line 263

Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/test_learningbank/site/pages/models/TestMaker.php on line 265
```

And printing out the file gives me:

```
{"name":"Vaks-DCK.mp4","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":1,"size":0}
```

Worth noticing here is that error = 1 and size = 0??

Comment: You're using a dot in many `./site/resources/upload/test_module/` but left it out for `$path = "/site/resources/upload/test_module/"` which could be a contributing factor. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. It could be a path issue and/or something else.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sadly this didn't do the trick :s

Comment: Did adding error reporting give back any errors/results? Does the folder have write permissions set also? Uploading requires an enctype also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no error nor result but the upload is done with ajax i have been able to upload before but right now im unable to upload any file what so ever.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i got a response in the ajax:
<b>Warning</b>:  chmod(): No such file or directory in <b>/var/www/test_learningbank/site/pages/models/TestMaker.php</b> on line <b>259</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  chmod(): No such file or directory in <b>/var/www/test_learningbank/site/pages/models/TestMaker.php</b> on line <b>261</b><br />

Comment: *Hm,* strange. I don't know what it could be then, other than a path issue.